# ORA-01843: not a valid month with data type conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I have created a view where one of column command is:

```
TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(sysdate ||' '||TIMING.TIME,'dd-MON-RRRR HH:MIAM'),'dd-MON-RRRR HH:MIAM') as time
```

The value of TIMING.TIME is like this: `09:30AM` as varchar2

When I run the query: `select TO_DATE(time,'DD-MON-RRRR HH:MIAM')from view`

I get the error

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

NLS Language is American.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TO_DATE(sysdate

That is wrong.

Never apply **TO_DATE** on **DATE** data type. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date. For date-arithmetic, leave the date as it is.

If you are trying to configure the time portion in current date, then:
1. First convert the date into string
2. Then concatenate the time portion to the string
3. Finally apply **TO_DATE**

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  2    ||' '
  3    ||'09:30AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miAM') TIME
  4  FROM dual;

TIME
----------------------
14-10-2015 09:30:00 AM
```

Remember,

- **TO_DATE** is used to **convert** a string into date.
- **TO_CHAR** is used to **display** the date in desired string format.

Modified query for you:

```
to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') ||' ' ||TIMING.TIME, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:miAM')
AS "TIME"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate` stores time and it would be better to convert it to char before concatenation

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd-MON-RRRR')||' '||TIMING.TIME
```