# why I got this error ora-01843 not a valid month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the following error ORA-01843: not a valid month

The query work fine when select data direct from
the column EVENT_DATE without converting to char

Its number field old design

When I convert  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE) its show the error

this is the query :

```
select a.clinic_no , a.doctor_no , 
from opd_visits_history a  
where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(event_date,'yyyymmdd'),'YY-MM-DD')  between '20231201' and '20231203'
```

and when use the query without conversion its working without error :

```
 select a.clinic_no , a.doctor_no , 
    from opd_visits_history a  
    where event_date  between 20231201 and 20231203
```

where is the error please ?

Comment: I think you misread the error message. It isn't complaining about `TO_CHAR`, it's complaining about `TO_DATE`. If it's a text column, it can contain anything.

Comment: If it works (enough) without the conversion then why are you converting it? And why are you converting to a date then to a string in a format (YY-MM-DD) that doesn't match the format of the fixed values you're comparing to? Anyway... some of your numbers don't represent real dates. I'd guess you might have 0 or 99999999 as dummy values, but could be anything. If you're on a recent version then use the `default on error` clause of the `to_date` function or `validate_conversion` to identify the values that don't convert successfully.

Comment: Also, you’re converting the date to a string in one format and then comparing it to a string in another format, which is never going to work e.g. you’re comparing  '23-12-01' to '20231201'

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776480/266304) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60606119/266304) to help identify non-convertible values.

Comment: Compare dates as dates, there's no any reason to convert date into string to check if it falls between two other dates. See [Datetime literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-01843: not a valid month with data type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120096/ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-with-data-type-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assuming `EVENT_DATE` is a `DATE` data type

`TO_DATE(event_date,'yyyymmdd')` will implicitly convert `event_date` to a string because `TO_DATE` expects the first argument to be a string and then will convert it back to a date.

The query is the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT clinic_no,
       doctor_no
FROM   opd_visits_history
WHERE  TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR(
             event_date,
             (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
           ),
           'yyyymmdd'
         ),
         'YY-MM-DD'
       ) BETWEEN '20231201' and '20231203'
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match `yyyymmdd` then you will try to convert to one format and then back in another and you are likely to get an exception (and if the month does not match the format then you will get `ORA-01843: not a valid month`).

Even if the implicit conversion did work, your query is still wrong as you will end up converting a `YY-MM-DD` formatted string to a `YYYYMMDD` formatted string which will not work as you expect.

What you should do is just compare dates (not strings):

```sql
SELECT clinic_no,
       doctor_no
FROM   opd_visits_history
WHERE  event_date >= DATE '2023-12-01'
AND    event_date <  DATE '2023-12-04'
```

*Note: in Oracle, a `DATE` always has both date and time components; unless your dates always have a midnight time component then you probably want to use `event_date < DATE '2023-12-04'` as the upper bound to include the entirety of the 24-hour period and including up to `2023-12-03 23:59:59` rather than `event_date <= DATE '2023-12-03'` which would have the upper bound as `2023-12-03 00:00:00`.*

---

```sql
select a.clinic_no , a.doctor_no
from   opd_visits_history a  
where  event_date  between 20231201 and 20231203
```

Also may not work and fail with `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`; again, if you are comparing dates then use `DATE` literals (or `TIMESTAMP` literals or use `TO_DATE` to convert strings to dates) on the right-hand side of the comparison.

---

#### Assuming `EVENT_DATE` is a `YYYYMMDD` formatted string

Since you are using (approximately) ISO8601 formatted strings then you do not need to perform any conversion to a `DATE` and can just use:

```sql
SELECT clinic_no,
       doctor_no
FROM   opd_visits_history
WHERE  event_date BETWEEN '20231201' AND '20231203'
```

*Note: But you really should store dates as `DATE` data-types and not as strings or numbers.*